# Is there any need to make an integer literal unsigned?

Tags: c++

I see lots of code doing things like,

```
static constexpr std::size_t value = 1024u;
```

I understand that `u` is specifying `1024` as an unsigned integer, but why bother with marking as `unsigned`?

Comment: Maybe "Explicit is better than implicit" !

Comment: @CinCout when using auto it makes sense, when the type is specified, what is the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point at all in writing `u` in your case as the compiler will make the conceptual conversion. It's a bad habit to get into insfar that it can introduce portability issues.

It is occasionally necessary though: `std::accumulate` is an important example - the type of the initial value is the type of the result.

If you were to use `auto` then you'll see that the rules become quite involved. For example, if you use a hexadecimal literal then the `unsigned` types become candidates.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal